# Using KDE services/apps without running plasma workspace

Tags: kde, awesome

How can I use KDE services without actually running the whole plasma workspace ?

I want to use awesomewm but I couldn't manage to run KDE services without actually running `plasma-desktop`. My point is I don't want to run everything under xterm(or other terminals) and want to use KDE's GUI tools and services(like network manager, device mounter etc.)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Have you had a look at this yet?](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/KDE_and_awesome)

Comment: @sr_, yes, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I did exactly what's explained in that link. KDE services just don't start.

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of the plasma5 messing me up, so I switched to openbox.
When I login, several services are already running, including kded, but the services under kded are not.

I would manually start kscreen2 from the kde-config screen, but this grew tiresome after a while.

I found to manually start kscreen I could run

```
qdbus org.kde.kded5 /kded  loadModule kscreen
```

For NetworkManager, that is being started by the system. 
I suspect you are looking for the nm-applet for you window manager.